# linux ftp command line get files with specific names

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp, command-line-interface

I'm trying to download a lot of logs but I only want those of a certain fail name. For example of the 1000s of logs they are all named like this

```
ABC_20161001_01.log
ABC_20161001_02.log
ABC_20161001_03.log
ADD_20161001_01.log
ADD_20161001_02.log
...
```

I tried using mget to do this

```
mget *20161001*
```

But it doesnt do anything. How best can I match on partial file name so I can get all the logs for 20161001. Im on ubuntu 14.x

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks ok to me.

But from http://www.thesqlreport.com/?p=143 you should start with

```
ftp> bin
ftp> prompt no
ftp> mget *20161001*
```

And if you're not on the right side, use `mput`:

```
ftp> mput *20161001*
```

Comment: Yeah I think the issue was the directory I was in was too large so it would time out when trying to do ^ . I ended up using lftp which seemed to handle stuff better. Thanks though!